# Youtube API loadVideoByUrl() function

Tags: javascript, php, youtube, youtube-api, addeventlistener

I've got this code, which add videos (and videos infos) of a YouTube channel ($_POST) on a div of the Html code, and I want to play a video in the Youtube player after click on an element:

```
    var args= "url="+urlchaine;
    xhr_object.open("POST", "traitement.php", true);
    xhr_object.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    if(xhr_object.readyState == 4) {
            eval(xhr_object.responseText);
        }
        return xhr_object.readyState;
}
xhr_object.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr_object.send(args);
```

traitement.php :

```
<?php
 if ( isset($_POST["url"]) && !empty($_POST["url"]) )
$urlchaine = $_POST["url"];
 else
$urlchaine = null;

 $stringresult = str_replace("http://www.youtube.com/user/", "",$urlchaine);

 require_once "Zend/Loader.php";
 Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_YouTube');
 $yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
 $videoFeed = $yt->getVideoFeed('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/...');

 if ( $stringresult != null){
  echo "var mydiv = document.getElementById('vids');";
  echo "var newcontent = document.createElement('div');";

  foreach ($videoFeed as $v): $thumbs = $v->getVideoThumbnails();
echo "newcontent.innerHTML = '...'";
echo "mydiv.appendChild(newcontent.firstChild);";
  endforeach;
  echo "img_videos.addEventListener('click',function () {
     $('#ytplayer_footer').fadeIn('normal');
     var idvideo = this.getAttribute('idvideo');
     var ytplayer = document.getElementById('ytplayer');

     ytplayer.loadVideoByUrl('...'); // ****** Here the problem

     ytplayer.playVideo();
  },false);";
 ?>
```

And I have this error : Object # has no method 'loadVideoByUrl'
What's wrong in my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have some quote escaping issues going on here. Take a look at this line:

```
var ytplayer = document.getElementById("ytplayer");
```

You're using double quotes, but your "echo" statement also uses double quotes. Switch that to single quotes and see what happens. I'm somewhat surprised this code runs at all.

(Looks like the question was changed)

The other thing to look out for is that you don't seem to be loading the YouTube JS anywhere. You're loading the PHP client library which runs server-side, but you also need to load the JavaScript libraries client side - otherwise you're just trying to call "loadVideoByUrl()" on a vanilla DOM object.

Comment: Did you change the question?

Comment: How can I do that ? I tried calling onYouTubePlayerReady() function before the loadVideoByUrl call but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: My suggestion for you is this: try making this work with the sample code (which I have confirmed is working) on a regular HTML page. Then go ahead and convert that to PHP. It'll be much easier to debug if we remove extraneous variables that may be causing issues.